# HTML5 semantic tag best practices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am building web site for a company.

Below the nav tag, I need to place a carousel with images that shows some of the accomplishments of the company.

What semantic tag should I use, section, article or a div? Should I use figure for every image in the carousel?

Below the carousel, they are 3 more images with logos of the partners of the company. This part has a title.

Below them, I have 3 images horizontally positioned, that shows the services that the company offers. This part has a title too.

What semantic tag should I use for the image parts, and should I use figure for every image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter too much which semantic tag you use. I would wrap the Carousel in a section tag. I would use figure for each image. Then you can also use figcaption if you need one.

As for the images below the carousel i would use a section tag again and inside this section i  would have 3 article tags with the image inside each one. In the CSS give each one a `width: 33%` and a `diaplay: inline;` and `float: left`.

For the header text put it before the first article and `text-align: center`.

Comment: Semantic tags are meant to replace meaningless div's all over the place so by having articles inside section its easier to follow and looks more structured.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! I don't know if wrapping the images in the carousel with figure tag is the best way here, because it is not referenced in any text (the page doesn't contains any text). Also, why should I put images in the galleries in article tags and not in figure tag, if the carousel images are figure tags?

Comment: see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel for carousel. Well i would have them in articles so i could set each width etc. You could put the figure inside the article tags.

Comment: I already developed the site, I just need to change div tags with appropriate HTML5 semantic tags, so I don't want to use article for positioning, but semantic purposes. Is there any semantic purpose for the article tag in this case?

Comment: There is no semantic purpose for the article tag other than in your own workflow i allows put articles in sections is i need to break down the content. So then when i look back over my code i can see oh thats a section with three articles(sub sections). They do nothing different than having a div. Other than you can target all articles or sections or asides or navs and so on with the css selector for that one rather than adding classes to each div. If you already have the site up i wouldnt bother changing unless you have to. Hope this makes sense it does in my head just not sure if it does hre